# Checking miracast compatible devices using android app

Tags: android, video-streaming, wifi, wifi-direct

How can I search for Miracast compatible devices (may be using WiFi Direct) in android?

I just got to know that DisplayManager and Presentation class in Android 4.2 help in presentation & miracast. But is there any way I can check if the other device is Miracast compatible / search Miracast sink?

Thanks
Smitha

Answer (score 2):

android framework source codes shows how to search miracast sink devices.

basically using WiFi Direct devices search API,
discoverPeers -> requestPeers -> isWifiDisplay & isPrimarySinkDeviceType

```
private static boolean isWifiDisplay(WifiP2pDevice device) {
    return device.wfdInfo != null
           && device.wfdInfo.isWfdEnabled()
           && isPrimarySinkDeviceType(device.wfdInfo.getDeviceType());
}

private static boolean isPrimarySinkDeviceType(int deviceType) {
    return deviceType == WifiP2pWfdInfo.PRIMARY_SINK
           || deviceType == WifiP2pWfdInfo.SOURCE_OR_PRIMARY_SINK;
}
```

https://github.com/kensuke/How-to-Miracast-on-AOSP/wiki/wfd_scan

WifiP2pWfdInfo defined four device types,

```
public static final int WFD_SOURCE              = 0;
public static final int PRIMARY_SINK            = 1;
public static final int SECONDARY_SINK          = 2;
public static final int SOURCE_OR_PRIMARY_SINK  = 3;
```

http s://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pWfdInfo.java

if you don't familiar with wifi direct, maybe my app is useful for using wifi direct api.

http s://github.com/kensuke/WiFiDirectTestApp

---

ADD: 2014/02/24 - parse toString output String for recognize Miracast devices Source or Sink

Wi-Fi Direct API requestPeers() callback to onPeersAvailable(), this method's parameter WifiP2pDeviceList has near by P2p devices that is a list of WifiP2pDevice instances, WifiP2pDevice has one device Wi-fi Direct information including Miracast information(wfd..) and device into can get uses WifiP2pDevice.toString() method.

Search "WFD DeviceInfo: XXX" String, XXX is a numerical value, masked "0x03" (see WifiP2pWfdInfo.java), after masked we get 0-3. That value defined SOURCE or SINK, see WifiP2pWfdInfo.java constants).

```
private static final int WFD_SOURCE = 0;
private static final int PRIMARY_SINK = 1;
private static final int SECONDARY_SINK = 2;
private static final int SOURCE_OR_PRIMARY_SINK = 3;
```

This *very duty* way can using on non rooted device, general app.

Sample of WifiP2pDevice.toString() returned value
"Device: ZTS1145
   deviceAddress: 7a:e8:b6:f6:4d:74
   primary type: 10-0050F204-5
   secondary type: null
   wps: 392
   grpcapab: 0
   devcapab: 33
   status: 3
   wfdInfo: WFD enabled: trueWFD DeviceInfo: 273
   WFD CtrlPort: 7236
   WFD MaxThroughput: 10"

```
// callback method of requestPeers();
public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {
    List<WifiP2pDevice> devs = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>(peers.getDeviceList());
    for (int i = 0; i < devs.size(); i++) {
        WifiP2pDevice dev = devs.get(i);
        boolean src = isWifiDisplaySource(dev);
        boolean sink = isWifiDisplaySink(dev);
        Log.d(TAG, dev.deviceName + " isSource[" + src + "] isSink[" + sink + "]");
    }
}

private static final int WFD_DISABLED = -1;
private static final int WFD_SOURCE = 0;
private static final int PRIMARY_SINK = 1;
private static final int SECONDARY_SINK = 2;
private static final int SOURCE_OR_PRIMARY_SINK = 3;

private static final int DEVICE_TYPE = 0x3;

private int getWFDDeviceInfoFromString(String devStr) {
    if (devStr == null) {
        return WFD_DISABLED;
    }

    boolean wfd = false;
    for (String line : devStr.split("\n")) {
        // start self parsing...
        // TODO: sprintf parse is more easy

        // search "WFD enabled: [true|false]"
        if (!line.matches(".*WFD enabled:.*")) {
            continue;
        }

        String[] tokens = line.split(":");
        int toks = tokens.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < toks - 1; i++) {
            if (!tokens[i].contains("WFD enabled")) {
                continue;
            }

            String tok = tokens[i + 1].replaceAll("\\s", ""); // delete white space
            if (tok.startsWith("true")) {
                wfd = true;
                break;
            }
            // why didn't use .equals() instead of .contains() and .startsWith() ? because
            // 1) "wfdInfo: WFD enabled: trueWFD DeviceInfo: 273"          // inputed string
            // 2) "(wfdInfo):( WFD enabled):( trueWFD DeviceInfo):( 273)"  // : splited string
            // 3) "( trueWFD DeviceInfo)" => "trueWFD DeviceInfo"          // white space deleted
        }
    }
    if (!wfd) {
        return WFD_DISABLED;
    }

    for (String line : devStr.split("\n")) {
        // search "WFD DeviceInfo: \d+"
        if (!line.matches(".*WFD DeviceInfo:.*")) {
            continue;
        }

        String[] tokens = line.split(":");
        int toks = tokens.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < toks - 1; i++) {
            if (!tokens[i].contains("WFD DeviceInfo")) {
                continue;
            }

            String tok = tokens[i + 1].replaceAll("\\s", "");
            int deviceInfo = Integer.parseInt(tok);
            Log.d(TAG, "line[" + line + "] DeviceInfo[" + deviceInfo + "] masked[" + (deviceInfo & DEVICE_TYPE) + "]");
            return deviceInfo;
        }
    }

    return WFD_DISABLED;
}

private boolean isWifiDisplaySource(WifiP2pDevice dev) {
    if (dev == null) {
        return false;
    }

    int deviceInfo = getWFDDeviceInfoFromString(dev.toString());
    if (deviceInfo == WFD_DISABLED) {
        return false;
    }

    int deviceType = deviceInfo & DEVICE_TYPE; // masked
    return deviceType == WFD_SOURCE || deviceType == SOURCE_OR_PRIMARY_SINK;
}

private boolean isWifiDisplaySink(WifiP2pDevice dev) {
    if (dev == null) {
        return false;
    }

    int deviceInfo = getWFDDeviceInfoFromString(dev.toString());
    if (deviceInfo == WFD_DISABLED) {
        return false;
    }

    int deviceType = deviceInfo & DEVICE_TYPE; // masked
    return deviceType == PRIMARY_SINK || deviceType == SOURCE_OR_PRIMARY_SINK;
}
```

Comment: Hi Kensuke, Are you aware that the APIs you are talking about are marked as hidden in the Android Source code. This means they are not taking along for SDK generation. As such these APIs cannot be used by regular apps on standard phones. You can offcourse build your own custom version of the Android operating system which alters this behaviour. Do you agree with this?

Comment: Complete correct your comment! My first answer using only system app. So, posted duty way for normal app...